# Почему не всегда наследуются proxy_set_header

Tags: nginx

proxy_set_header в родительском блоке server работают для первого дочернего блока location (~ ^/(auth|wh)), а для второго (/ws) - нет. Почему так?

```
server {
        ...
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        location ~ ^/(auth|wh) {
            proxy_pass ...
        }

        location /ws {
            proxy_pass ...
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_read_timeout 1h;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Потому что так написано [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header):

> Директивы **наследуются** с предыдущего уровня **при условии**, что на данном уровне **не описаны** свои директивы `proxy_set_header`.

Comment: В дочернем уровне не описана директива proxy_set_header X-Real-IP, значит она должна наследоваться с родительского. Или тут нет индивидуализации каждого proxy_set_header?

Comment: @Александр если есть хоть один `proxy_set_header`, то не наследуется ничего.

Comment: аа, ясно, спасибо!